# NivoSlider - Weird Pixel Jump on Control Nav when hovering over

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

I'm currently working on a wp template containing a nivo slider, which worked fine till something weird happened. Whenever I hover over the slider, the buttons inside the control nav are moving 1-2 px to the right. This happens only in Chrome, in FF it works fine (however, the buttons are 1px below the active button). I tried using Firebug, but i didn't get any clue, what's happening.

The slider regarding part of my css:

```
#wrapper, #slider {
height: 504px;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

The Nivo Slider CSS:
http://pastebin.com/p0YTYrWg

The Slider theme css:
http://pastebin.com/aKD2W1Pj

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
Had to add "backface-visibility: hidden;"